# Passing tab id in 'chrome.tabs.executeScript()'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, callback

I have a chrome extension which is a popup.
It has got a background script. In this script file, I am trying to insert a code to execute in all the open tabs.

This is how I do it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < tablist.length; ++i) {                
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tablist[i].id, { file: "js/fuse.min.js"}, function (result) {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(<i want to get tab id here>, { code: code });                
            });
        }
```

I have nested the 'executeScript()' cause I require an external file to be included.

Since the inner function is a callback, it is asynchronous and I won't get the tab id from the parent function.

How will I get the tabid to be passed inside the nested function? The 'result' argument doesn't have it.

Comment: Use `let` instead of `var` so you can simply repeat `tablist[i].id`. More info: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](//stackoverflow.com/q/750486)

Comment: Can you pass `id` as a second parameter to the callback?

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried it. But it says 'i' is not defined. I think that this solution works only if it is a normal function. My case is different. It is a callback function.

Comment: @Nuhman nope. it didn't work. I would really appreciate if you could help with a solution.

Comment: @AnilPBabu, `let` must work, it's standard JavaScript, nothing special about callbacks in this scenario, so you must have made a mistake somewhere. Maybe you've changed `tablist` after the loop, or something else.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes.. it works when i triple checked. I wonder what happened when I checked last time. sorry about that. could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Try this javascript closure trick:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tablist.length; ++i) { 
   (function(i) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tablist[i].id, { file: "js/fuse.min.js"}, function (result) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(<i want to get tab id here>, { code: code });                
        });
     })(i);             
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution! It solved my issue. For someone who's looking at the code, to access the tab ID inside the innermost executeScript function as OP wanted, that innermost line can be rewritten as: `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tablist[i].id, { code: code }); `